# Fit Image in DIV as a background which contains height less than division (Different)

Tags: html, css

Need to fit bigger background image in small div exactly. when I use background-size:cover; the image is not fitting exactly. the reason was I made my div as 400px height and width 100%.

**In small devices it's working fine.**

[image]

**the same way when I resize to big screen, it was not able to fit to div.**

[image]

**Process to prodduce:**
Please check in below fiddle and resize the output window to smaller as well as bigger. [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Rayudu/s4ruuc3j/)

[**original image link**](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_EqZzf-l7OCg/TNmdtcyGBZI/AAAAAAAAAD8/KD5Y23c24go/s1600/homer-simpson-1280x1024.jpg)

**Code:**

```css
#imagecontainer {
    
    background: url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_EqZzf-l7OCg/TNmdtcyGBZI/AAAAAAAAAD8/KD5Y23c24go/s1600/homer-simpson-1280x1024.jpg") no-repeat;
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position:center center;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagecontainer">
  hi
  dadsa
  <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
   <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
   <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
   <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: I tried with all mentioned answers from stack overflow. No one having height. but I have height for my div. So, please down vote my question, even if check my code and let me know why I was not able to fit the image in div.

Comment: Are you saying Homer's head is cut off? I believe that the background is doing what 'cover' means. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/ The size of the element cannot change ration and have the images somehow maintain your intended ratio.

Comment: Do you actually want normally flowed text inside or what's going to go inside? depending on the content inside you can do something like use padding to create the aspect ratio of the image and it will scale and all of the image will always be shown https://jsfiddle.net/s4ruuc3j/1/

Answer (score 1):

Set `background-image size to 100% 100%` i.e. it's height and width and thus this makes it look same on both `mobile devices` and on `large screen`, but it will looks bit stretch on large screen.

> background-size:cover - Scales the image as large as possible and
>   maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't get squished). The image
>   "covers" the entire width or height of the container. When the image
>   and container have different dimensions, the image is clipped either
>   left/right or top/bottom.

Whereas property value `cover` for `background-image` scale image and that's why it looks different at other `break points`.

```css
#imagecontainer {
    background: url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_EqZzf-l7OCg/TNmdtcyGBZI/AAAAAAAAAD8/KD5Y23c24go/s1600/homer-simpson-1280x1024.jpg") no-repeat;
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagecontainer">
  hi
  dadsa
  <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
   <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
   <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
   <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a transparent png image with background color.

```css
#imagecontainer {
    
    background:rgb(125,126,125)  url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2a/Wikipe-tan_in_navy_uniform2_transparent.png") no-repeat;
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    
     -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  -o-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position:center center;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagecontainer">
  hi
  dadsa
  <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
   <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
   <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
   <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to change some css on imagecontainer id so can overcome from your problem

```css
#imagecontainer {
    
  background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: hsl(211, 58%, 53%);
background-image: url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_EqZzf-l7OCg/TNmdtcyGBZI/AAAAAAAAAD8/KD5Y23c24go/s1600/homer-simpson-1280x1024.jpg");
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto !important;
border: 1px solid;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagecontainer">
  hi
  dadsa
  <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
   <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
   <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
   <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
</div>
```